# Google Maps исчезают маркеры при повороте экрана

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio-2015, google-maps, xamarin

[image: Вертикальная ориентация]

При повороте экрана исчезает маркер, как показано на рисунке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В отладчике проверял, он вызывает все методы прорисовки, но activity всё равно пустой. Может кто знает в чем тут проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: 
создать наследника от MapFragment

```
public class RetainMapFragment : MapFragment
{
    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        RetainInstance = true;
    }
}
```

Затем задать у фрагмента класс

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="5px"
    class="com.example.androidmapex.RetainMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за того, что происходит смена жизненного цикла Android 
Попробуй в манифесте в активити прописать

android:configChanges="screensize|orientation"

Comment: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'screensize|orientation'), у меня версия Android API16 (Android 4.1)